# creating a function to compare values of a variables via arithmetic operations across levels of another variable

Tags: r, function, data.table, tidyverse, arithmetic-expressions

I want help to create a function that does the following operations:

- create a new variable named `division`
- put in each row `r_n` of the variable `dT$division` the result of the  division of the value of the corresponding row `r_n` of `dT$result1` by
  the value of each row of `dT$result1` for `dt$treat == A`
- create a new variable named `operation`
- for each row of the variable `operation` execute 
  `dT$operation = (2*(dT$division-1))/(2*(dT$division-1)+1)`

Where `n` in `r_n` is the number of each row in the data frame, and takes values from `1 to N`, and N is the total number of observations or rows in the data frame.

**#sample data**

(note: edited to add the variable `id` which is vital to create the desired function)

```
dT = read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id group treat result1
1 0 A 0.1438 
2 0 A 0.237 
3 0 B 0.2774 
4 0 B 0.2774 
5 0 B 0.2093 
6 0 C 0.1206 
7 0 C 0.1707 
8 0 C 0.0699 
9 0 C 0.1351 
10 1 C 0.1206 
11 1 A 0.1438 
12 1 A 0.237 
13 1 B 0.2774 
14 1 B 0.2774 
15 1 B 0.2093 
16 1 C 0.1206 
17 1 C 0.1707 
18 1 C 0.0699
19 1 C 0.1351 
20 1 C 0.1206")
```

**#head output**

(note: this is a random sample of rows from the original data chosen to facilitate the illustration of the concept)

```
id group treat result1
1 0 A 0.014
2 0 A 0.02
3 0 B 0.20
4 1 A 0.14
5 1 B 0.27
```

**#expected output**

(note: for dT$treat.denominator A2 and A3, this example only shows the visual - because I needed to post the expected output as soon as possible; that means that I calculated the actual values of the variables dT$division and dT$operation only for dT$treat.denominator A1)

```
id group treat result1 treat.numerator treat.denominator division operation
1 0 A 0.01 A1 A1 1.00 0.00
2 0 A 0.02 A2 A1 1.64 0.56
3 0 B 0.20 B3 A1 20.00 0.97
4 1 A 0.14 A4 A1 14.00 0.96
5 1 B 0.27 B5 A1 27.00 0.98
1 0 A 0.01 A1 A2 1.00 0.00
2 0 A 0.02 A2 A2 1.64 0.56
3 0 B 0.20 B3 A2 20.00 0.97
4 1 A 0.14 A4 A2 14.00 0.96
5 1 B 0.27 B5 A2 27.00 0.98
1 0 A 0.01 A1 A3 1.00 0.00
2 0 A 0.02 A2 A3 1.64 0.56
3 0 B 0.20 B3 A3 20.00 0.97
4 1 A 0.14 A4 A3 14.00 0.96
5 1 B 0.27 B5 A3 27.00 0.98
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: what is your expected results?

Comment: Hi, @Onyambu. Just edited the question to add expected output as requested. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a new variable named division
2. put in each row r_n of the variable dT$division the result of the division of the value of the corresponding row r_n of dT$result1 by the value of each row of dT$result1 for dt$treat == A

**Answer to Steps 1 and 2**

```
  division<-dT$result1/dT$result1[dT$treat=="A"]  

  dT<-cbind(dT,division)
```

3. create a new variable named operation
4. for each row of the variable operation execute  dT$operation = (2*(dT$division-1))/(2*(dT$division-1)+1)

**Answers to 3 and 4**

```
dT$operation<-(2*(dT$division-1))/(2*(dT$division-1)+1)
```

Comment: Thanks, @JorgeLopez. But it does not yield the expected output.

Comment: Hello there Krantz, I was following as per your instructions. There was no further input in your requirements. If the output is not the same as your expected result, would you please check your directions again?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Likely I will post another question after reviewing the instructions.  I will let you know. Thanks a lot for this great answer. Very helpful.